# How to consume messages from kafka topics using protocol buffers (protobuf) by spring cloud stream binder kafka streams dependency?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, protobuf-java

I have an application that consumes messages in a protobuf format and when I run it I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "NotificationProcessorService-process-applicationId-0300a3f8-6dab-4f3f-a631-8719178823ce-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:865)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:938)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:640)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 10, 8, 57, 53, 52, 50, 56, 51, 51, 51, 16, -7, -12, -106, -97, -119, 47, 26, 6, 57, 56, 55, 56, 54, 55, 34, 4, 56, 54, 50, 50, 42, 6, 56, 57, 55, 51, 50, 57, 50, 5, 80, 82, 73, 77, 69, 58, 5, 56, 55, 57, 50, 51, 65, 31, -123, -21, 81, -72, 93, -108, 64, 72, 2, 82, 6, 67, 82, 69, 68, 73, 84, 89, 31, -123, -21, 81, -72, 93, -108, 64, 97, -26, -48, 34, -37, -7, 74, 64, 64, 105, -26, -48, 34, -37, -7, 74, 64, 64, 113, -26, -48, 34, -37, -7, 74, 64, 64, 122, 4, 77, 65, 73, 76]] from topic [pos-proto-topic]
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x4ff0a08 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #1, byte #7)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.reportInvalid(UTF32Reader.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.read(UTF32Reader.java:158)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._loadMore(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:250)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2384)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:672)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._initForReading(ObjectReader.java:357)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2064)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1555)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:517)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:865)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:938)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:640)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510)
```

I think the application expects a Json message by default and I need to change some configuration saying "hey, I am waiting for protobuf messages here". I feel I searched by the whole internet and didn't find how to set it.

Here is my application.yaml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        notification-input-channel:
          destination: pos-proto-topic

        notification-output-channel:
          destination: notification-topic
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: localhost:9092
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
          bindings:
            notification-output-channel:
              producer:
                valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerde
```

I am also using the Hoxton.SR9 as spring-cloud.version. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.<channel-name>-in-0.consumer.valueSerde
```